# She heard two gunshots with a woman screaming / scream in between

Tags: word-difference

The sentence below is from my English exercise book:

> Fill in each blank with the correct form of the word in the bracket.
>
> She said she heard two gunshots with a woman ___ (scream) in between.

If I write "screaming", it means the woman was screaming continuously but she might not hear the rest. If I write "scream", it means the woman screamed just once.

Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in both cases.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use 'scream' in this case.
It should be 'a woman's scream' for it to be correct.

Comment: While this answer is correct, the use of *screaming* would also be correct.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.